# proxy.ashx for ArcGIS

Tags: proxy, arcgis

I downloaded source from http://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy for .net. My proxy.config is simple

Problem i am having is when i test my proxy ,it retrieves the info/data from the given URL but path for all .css ,image files is relative to my local machine.
My request looks like : "http://local.XYZ.com/wewportal/proxy.ashx?http://server.arcgisonline.com"
error i see in Firebug :"NetworkError: 404 Not Foundhttp://local.xyz.com/arcgis/rest/static/main.css"

my website is in MVC4 and proxy.ashx,proxy.config are in the root directory.Am i missing some setting on IIS ?

Thanks
Manvi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, your attributes are incorrectly formatted. Usually it's something like : http://www.example.com?variable_name=value&variable_second=value_second . I don't see any variable names in your url, just values -so something's up with that.

Edit: Okay, I got it working on my machine and yes, your attributes are missing an "=" sign. 
I opened up the readme and the direction state:

> *Test that the proxy is able to forward requests directly in the browser using:
>    
>    `http://[yourmachine]/DotNet/proxy.ashx?http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/?f=pjson`
>   
>   * Edit the proxy.config file in a text editor to set up your proxy configuration settings.
>   * Update your application to use the proxy for the specified services. In this JavaScript example requests to route.arcgis.com will utilize the proxy.

Because I put the files in the root directory for a test (and not in the DotNet folder) , I shortened the url. the working URL for me was: 
 `http://localhost:64875/proxy.ashx?http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/?f=pjson`

^^ note the ending has an "=" sign. depending on where your proxy.ashx file is you might need to use a different location.